# Run Template on the Cloud Dataflow service

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to running a local template I developed in Google DataFlow.

The problem is when I run it in Google Cloud Shell with:

```
python -m dataflow.py --project poc-cloud-209212 --temp_location gs://<...>
```

I got this error

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named apache_beam
```

So I tried with a simpler example: the [wordcount](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-python)

Like Google said, I execute:

```
python -m wordcount --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt --output gs://<...> --runner DataflowRunner --project <project> --temp_location gs://<...>
```

And I got this error:

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named past.builtins
```

If I execute without .py:

```
 python -m wordcount --input gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt --output gs://<...> --runner DataflowRunner --project <project> --temp_location gs://<...>
```

Again, the same error, but with "more" informatión

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/<...>/wordcount.py", line 26, in <module>
    from past.builtins import unicode
ImportError: No module named past.builtins
```

What is happening? How can I run those templates in Google Cloud Dataflow?

Do i need to set up the environment in Google Cloud like I did in local or is done by default?

Comment: I think you should specify the `setup.py` file in the root directory. Then pass it using --setup_file=/path/to/setup.py. The problem is that the workers don't see the imports. You can import locally within functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it.

This is how:

Install virtualenv with python 2.7 in Google Cloud(3.5 was installed by default and Dataflow can not use python3)

```
 virtualenv env --python=python2
```

After activate this virtualenv you can run in it